# Get a grid of unique combination from vector

Tags: r

I'd like to return a grid with unique rows from a sequence vector. I'm looking for a general solution so I can pass any number of sequences in a vector. I don't know the terminology for this, so how can I do this?

**Example**

```
num <- 3
v <- c(seq(1, num, 1))
```

**Desired Output**

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
```

Second and third column can be switched:

```
1 3 2
2 1 3
3 2 1
```

I tried manipulating `expand.grid()` but it requires sorting and filtering which seems excessive.

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired output. Are the row vectors cyclic permutations of `v`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I want the first col to sequence through each number. The second and third column are simply the sequence to the limit, then repeat. Column 2 and 3 can be switched. See edit.

Comment: not really sure if this is what you are wanting but one way to get your first outcome `f <- function(vec) { ;   n = length(vec) ;
  m = matrix(0, nr=n, nc=n) ;  m[] = vec[(col(m) + row(m) - 2) %% n + 1] ;  m }`. Then pass vector `f(1:3)`, `f(rnorm(5))` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another base R option

```
t(sapply(1:length(v), function(i) rep(v, 2)[i:(i+2)]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    1
#[3,]    3    1    2
```

Explanation: We cyclically permute `v` and store the vectors as column vectors in a matrix.

---

For general `v` (of length `length(v)`) this becomes

```
t(sapply(1:length(v), function(i) rep(v, 2)[i:(i + length(v) - 1)]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Base R is best.

Comment: Actually, it should be `t(sapply(1:length(v), function(i) rep(v, (length(v) - 1)[i:(i+(length(v) - 1)]))` Thanks!

Comment: @Vedda Are you sure? You should only need to `rep` the original vector twice, since we're making sure that we're staying within the limits in the `sapply` loop `1:length(v)` and the corresponding indices `i:(i+2)`.

Comment: Yes, change the length of the vector from 3 to 4 and it makes three columns when 4 is needed.

Comment: @Vedda No I don't think that's quite correct. You *do* need to change the indices (which is clear and not what I was referring to), but you only need to `rep` once. Here's a reproducible example: `v <- seq_len(4); t(sapply(1:length(v), function(i) rep(v, 2)[i:(i+3)]))`; so for general `v`, the indices will be `i:(i + length(v) - 1)` (which is what you wrote); then `rep(v, 2)` suffices. Try it out:-)

Comment: Yes, correct. I was looking for a general solution as you have provided with the edit. This was a big help. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No worries @Vedda, glad it was helpful. I misunderstood what you meant in the beginning but we got there in the end:-)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `permn` from `combinat` package which generates all possible permutations of `v` and then select top `num` of them using `head`

```
head(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, combinat::permn(v))), num)

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2  3
#2  1  3  2
#3  3  1  2
```

We can also use `sample` to select any `num` rows instead of first `num` rows using `head`.

where

```
combinat::permn(v) #gives
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 1 2

#[[4]]
#[1] 3 2 1

#[[5]]
#[1] 2 3 1

#[[6]]
#[1] 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution (column order differs but the idea holds):

```
n = 3
sweep(replicate(n, 1:n), 2, 1:n, "+") %% n + 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    1    2
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    2    3    1
```

**Explanation**:

`replicate` will first create a matrix where each row is `1:n`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

I then use the `sweep` function to add `1` to column 1, `2` to column 2, `3` to column 3:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6
```

At this point, you can do a modulo on the matrix and then add `1` to arrive at the desired matrix.

Edit: If you need to have the same column order as you had above, can do

```
(sweep(replicate(n, 1:n), 2, 1:n, "+") + 1) %% n + 1
```